# Languages in opencart

Tags: opencart

I want to show Languages dropdown in header using opencart sellya theme. on below link you will see languages dropdown in header. http://serwer1382018.home.pl/sellyakids/

But on locally its not showing me on frontend. see below code:

```
<div id="lc_dropdown"><?php echo $language; ?><?php echo $currency; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the new language in admin side: `System > Localisation > Language` page.
2. Now the language switch menu will be available in frontend as buttons/dropdown depending on the theme(the options will be wrapped in a form tag.).
3. Using css and javascript make it a dropdown selector.

Once the above steps are done, add files to the folder mentioned in the `System > Localisation > Language` page to fetch the new language translation data.

Answer (score 0):

To Add Language Dropdown on Opencart Website follow below steps,

1. Download the language pack you need. You can  [search the OpenCart marketplace](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension&path=2)
2. Unzip it and upload the files to your main shop directory. Note: If there is an upload folder inside the archive, upload the contents of that folder, not the folder itself.
3. Go to OpenCart admin panel **System > Localisation > Languages**
4. Click "Add New". The details that you have to fill in the form are usually supplied in the "Documentation" tab on the OpenCart extension page of the language pack. You might also find them in a text file inside the installation archive.
5. Click on **save** button.
6. At front end you will see the new language is added in language drop down.